# How to use bash completion-functions that are defined on-the-fly?

Tags: bash, bash-completion

I try to add a completion for the alias: `alias m='man'`.
So, I added `complete -F _man m` to my `.bashrc`.

The problem is that the function `_man` used for completing, isn't defined at the start of the bash session but is defined when performing the first tab-competition on the `$ man` command.
So:
`$ complete -p | grep _man` can either return nothing, or return:

```
complete -F _man man
complete -F _man apropos
complete -F _man whatis
```

Therefore, when I try to tab-complete on `$ m` command, I can get:

```
$ m -bash: completing : function « _man » not found
$ m
```

And I have the same problem with the functions `_aptitude` and `_apt-get`

---

*What I would like, is to use my `.bashrc` to force the creation of the functions `_man`, `_aptitude`, `_apt-get` as soon as bash starts.*
Maybe it is possible using `compgen` builtin.

My bash version is:
`GNU bash, version 4.2.45(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`

*Thanks for reading.*

---

**Edit:** In fact, a similar question already exists and has been answered:
- [bash-completion - completion function defined the first time a command is invoked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15858271) -

Comment: But the answer here is better than the ones in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15858271/bash-completion-completion-function-defined-the-first-time-a-command-is-invoke :) I'm going to add the answer there as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have in your `.bashrc`:

```
alias m='man'
complete -F _man m
```

Just add :

```
_completion_loader man
```

Then your completions on `$ m` will work fine, even without performing tab-completion on `$ man` before.

`_completion_loader`  may not be defined in your distribution. Here's a copy of the code found in a .bashrc of Ubuntu 14.04:

```
_completion_loader () 
{ 
    local compfile=./completions;
    [[ $BASH_SOURCE == */* ]] && compfile="${BASH_SOURCE%/*}/completions";
    compfile+="/${1##*/}";
    [[ -f "$compfile" ]] && . "$compfile" &> /dev/null && return 124;
    complete -F _minimal "$1" && return 124
}
```

---

Actually, to avoid generating the `_man` function twice, you should also change the line
`complete -F _man m` to
`complete -F _man man m`.