# How can I add bash tab completion dynamically?

Tags: bash, bash-completion

I have a program that is similar to git in that `git foo` and `git-foo` are both valid ways to invoke it.  I have rudimentary tab completion written for the `git foo` version, and I would like to use it for `git-*`.  But for various reasons, it's non-trivial (in fact, impossible since I can add new commands at any time) to know the list of all `git-*` commands before hand, so I need a way to run something like

```
complete -F _my_git_completion git-*
```

But that line doesn't work since expands `git-*` at the time of invocation with files that are in the current directory.  This isn't helpful since my files aren't in the current directory.

I vaguely remember a hook that's called the first time completion is tried for a new executable, but I can't find it now.  Is there such a thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it turns out there is this older question:
[bash-completion - completion function defined the first time a command is invoked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15858271/bash-completion-completion-function-defined-the-first-time-a-command-is-invoke)
so I should have searched harder.